# Is there a way to set the URL of the session timeout redirect?

Tags: salesforce1-app, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, session, hybrid

I am playing around building a hybrid app that wraps the Salesforce1 UI in the Mobile SDK. It's a local app in that the first page of my app is a splash page that runs locally in iOS -- localhost[slash]index.html. A user clicks through from that first splash page into Salesforce1 out on the web. In my app, sometimes when my session times out, I am redirected back to my local index.html page and sometimes I am redirected to salesforce.com and there doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason why one happens vs. the other.

The problem is that in a hybrid app that just points to a mydomain/one/one.app. If that app inside of the hybrid container redirects to salesforce.com, I'm stuck without a way to navigate back to my app (i.e. I can't get back to my localhost[slash]index.html).

Incidentally, and I don't know if this matters at all, but when I am redirected to salesforce.com, the page is completely unstyled (no CSS).

Is there any way to ensure that a session timeout would redirect back to my local page?